# LINQ Orderby with Country name "India" first in list then remaining

Tags: linq

How to write LINQ query using lambda expression with below requirment.

LINQ Orderby with Country name "India" first in list then remaining

```
.OrderBy(m=>m.Country("India"))
.ThenBy(m=>m.LastName);
```

Its not working

Please provide me good solution.

thanks
Surya

Comment: Is `m.Country` a method?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.OrderByDescending(m => m.Country == "India").ThenBy(m => m.LastName);
```

This will result in India being the first entry in the result and the remaining countries being unordered. If you want the remaining countries to be ordered alphabetically, change the code to this:

```
.OrderByDescending(m => m.Country == "India")
.ThenBy(m => m.Country)
.ThenBy(m => m.LastName);
```